# Ошибка при нажатии на item в RecyclerView Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

ошибка возникает при нажатие на элемент из RecyclerView Если можете помогите, пожалуйста, вот код адаптера:

```
package com.example.fin_reg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.fin_reg.ModelResponse.ListTeacherGroupResponse.Student;
import com.example.fin_reg.ui.StudentTeacherInfo.StudentTeacherInfoFragment;

import java.util.List;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder >{
    List<Student> students;
    Context context;

    public UserAdapter(Context context, List<Student> students) {
        this.context = context;
        this.students = students;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_users, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.username.setText(students.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)v.getContext();
                StudentTeacherInfoFragment studentTeacherInfoFragment = new StudentTeacherInfoFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.recycler_stud_of_group, studentTeacherInfoFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView username, organization;

         public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_username);
            organization = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_organization);
        }
    }

}
```

Что выводит в ошибке:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fin_reg, PID: 27706
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:4101)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3835)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3330)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.horizontalSolvingPass(Direct.java:234)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveHorizontalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:596)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.horizontalSolvingPass(Direct.java:286)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:118)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:792)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:583)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:355)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solveVerticalMatchConstraint(Direct.java:636)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:407)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.verticalSolvingPass(Direct.java:446)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.Direct.solvingPass(Direct.java:178)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:642)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solveLinearSystem(BasicMeasure.java:159)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:290)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:119)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1578)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1690)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Впервые такую ошибку вижу. Скорее всего вы не тот ID указываете. Что такое `R.id.recycler_stud_of_group`? Возможно, вам надо другой ID указать?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, спасибо. Исправил на id constraintlayout и при клике фрагмент не открывается, может Вы знаете почему?Спасибо

Comment: Причин много может быть. Может ID всё таки не тот или в разметке что-то не то.

Comment: Спасибо!Решил проблему, дело было в Id